# Heroku deployment error: Cannot find module '../models/User'

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment

**Heroku Logs**

```
2021-07-21T11:36:31.433312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-07-21T11:36:35.175691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-21T11:36:35.256063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109475+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109505+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109506+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109506+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109506+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/User'
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109507+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109507+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/config/passport-config.js
2021-07-21T11:36:35.109508+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
```

**My app directory**

[image]

I have also set .env variable
[image]

**Can any body help me!! It will very helpfull for me**

Answer (score 0):

I've read some answers saying heroku is case sensetive. If so, heroku is expecting models/User and getting models/user in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).